# How can i convert a polygon into a rectangle?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, polygon

I have a 4 side polygon that i draw on a video frame. I would like to take this polygon and make it a rectangle so i will be able to  treat it as a matrix.I want to take the smallest rectangle i can have but still  be as close as i can to the original vertices. 
Can anyone help me with that please? I've been trying to do it for a several days and with no success. Keep in mind that my polygon can be completely not parallel to the axes and in that case i want to get a rectangle that is also not parallel to the axes. 
[image]

Comment: The search term you're looking for is 'minimum bounding box'

Comment: I'm  not sure that can help me. From what i understand the bounding box will be parallel with the figure axes.All i need to do is to be able to draw a rectangle on a picture frame, and the rectangle needs to be able to NOT be parallel to the figure axes. Isn't any nice and easy way to do such a simple task?

Comment: You need an OBB (oriented bounding box) - there is some C++ code [on Dave Eberly's site](http://www.geometrictools.com/LibMathematics/Containment/Containment.html) that you may be able to port to MATLAB.

Comment: There is [a nice PDF of the algorithm](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MinimumAreaRectangle.pdf) on the same site, if that helps.

Comment: Yes! I think that is what i need! But how do i port C++ code into MATLAB? I'm really new with this program and i my knowledge in C++ is even less.

Comment: [Google find some hits](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30402-feret-diameter-and-oriented-box/content/orientedBox/imOrientedBox.m) I'm sure there must be MATLAB examples now you know you need an OBB.